# Ubuntu sendmail - configuration issue

Tags: sendmail

I am able to sucessfully install sendmail in my ubuntu machine and able to send emails for gmail accounts but for other domain email accounts I am receiving the following errors:

```
 dsn=5.7.1, stat=User unknown
 SYSERR(root): localhost                                                                                        .localdomain. config error: mail loops back to me (MX problem?)
 localhost [127.0.0.1] d                                                                                        id not issue MAIL/EXPN/VRFY/ETRN during connection to MTA-v4
 dsn=5.3.5, stat=Local configuration error
```

please hep me find a solution

Comment: Could you execute the following command as non root user and post the results? `(echo subject: test; echo; echo test) | /usr/sbin/sendmail -v -i user@domain.net` [replace user@domain.net with non deliverable email address]`

Comment: This is the answer - the command will show verbose output including reason for failures.

Answer (score 0):

I have been fighting sendmail configuration for days and finally noticed that my old server wasn't using sendmail at all but was linking to msmtp. I did `sudo apt install msmtp` and copied over my configurations in `/etc/msmtprc`:

```
defaults

timeout 15
tls on
tls_starttls on
tls_certcheck on
tls_trust_file /etc/ssl/certs/ca-certificates.crt

account default

host EMAIL_SMTP_SERVER
port 587
auto_from off
from USERNAME@MYDOMAIN

auth on
user USERNAME@MYDOMAIN
password PASSWORD
```

Then I uninstalled sendmail (`sudo apt remove sendmail`)
and linked it to msmtp: `sudo ln -s /usr/bin/msmtp /usr/bin/sendmail`

Testing: `echo "Subject: Testing sendmail" | sendmail -v recipient_email@domain.com`